# populate dropdown box with a query from sql which has been JSON encoded

Tags: php, sql, json, loops, drop-down-menu

Ok, so I THINK this is kind of tricky. I had this code working to populate a dropdown box with text from the fields of a database (below) but now I have to change it so that instead of the names being in the dropdown I need {"Fullname":name(variable)}. First off here is my initial code:

```
<form name="ClientNameForm" id="ClientNameForm" action="ClientDetails.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="ClientName" id="ClientName" placeholder="Type Service User's name here:" style="width: 200px"/><br/><br/>
<select name="Name_dropdown" id="name_dropdown" style="width: 200px" >
    <?php
    $ClientName_Query= "SELECT CONCAT(FName, ' ', SName) AS FullName FROM ClientDetails";

    $ClientName_Result= mysql_query($ClientName_Query) or die (mysql_error());while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($ClientName_Result)){
        $Fullname=$row['FullName'];
        echo "<option> $Fullname </option>";

    }?>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

My attempts to alter this so far have fallen short in that in my dropdown box I am getting  {"Fullname":null} . The following was my php for what I explained was my aim earlier:

```
<?php
    $ClientName_Query= "SELECT CONCAT(FName, ' ', SName) AS FullName FROM ClientDetails";

    $ClientName_Result= mysql_query($ClientName_Query) or die (mysql_error());$EmptyArray=array();  
    while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($ClientName_Result)){

        $FullName=$row['FullName'];
        $Queue= array('FullName' => $ClientName_Result);
        array_unshift($Empty_array, $Queue);$Json_Encoded= json_encode($Queue);


        echo "<option> $Json_Encoded </option>";

}?>
```

I am very confused. All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Change

`$Queue= array('FullName' => $ClientName_Result);`

to

`$Queue= array('FullName' => $FullName);`

and remove `array_unshift($Empty_array, $Queue);`